How to set GitHub Actions up to fail if Xcode tests are failing?
I need to build an Xcode project with pods, run tests, and if tests are failing => fail workflow. If tests are passed => upload the report to Codecov.
Currently, it doesn't matter if tests are passed or failed, the workflow will be marked as passed successfully anyway.
This is my workflow:
name: Test
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - debug
jobs:
  xcode-tests:
    name: "Select OS"
    runs-on: macos-14-xlarge

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@master

    - name: Select Xcode
      run: sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode_15.2.app && /usr/bin/xcodebuild -version

    - name: Cache Cocoapods
      id: cache-cocoapods
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        path: Pods
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-pods-${{ hashFiles('**/Podfile.lock') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-pods-

    - name: Install Cocoapods
      run: pod install --repo-update

    - name: Build and Test
      env:
        scheme: ${{ 'ExampleApp' }}
        platform: ${{ 'iOS Simulator' }}
        device: ${{ 'iPhone 15' }}
        os_version: ${{ '17.4' }}
      run: xcodebuild test -workspace ExampleApp.xcworkspace -scheme ExampleApp -destination "platform=$platform,name=$device,OS=$os_version" -enableCodeCoverage YES build test | xcpretty --test

    - name: Upload coverage to Codecov
      uses: codecov/codecov-action@v4
      with:
        token: ${{ secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN }}


Did you try using xcodebuild ... || exit 1? This should return an error if the command fails. Otherwise, you could use a bash logic:  xcodebuild ... if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then echo "Success" else echo "Failed" exit 1 fi (something like that)

Does this answer your question? Xcode test failing does not failed Github action pipeline

The easiest way to achieve that is set -o pipefail
If any command in the pipeline fails - the entire pipeline will fail - not just the last command.
set -o pipefail && xcodebuild ... | xcpretty --test
